# Заявление пишут о или на?

Tags: канцеляризмы, согласование

Как правильно писать: "заявление о чем-то" или "заявление на что-то"? Например, "заявление об отпуске" или "заявление на отпуск"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Заявление** (просьба о чем-то, изложенная письменно в официальной форме) ***о
чем и на что***. [*Рагозин] написал заявление в две строки о том, чтобы его перевели на
военную работу (Федин). Подать заявление на развод (влияние глагола подать, ср. разг. 
подать на развод)*. [Здесь](http://www.interword.se/Syntax/Lektionsmaterial/Rozenthal_Rektion.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Заявление не может быть НА ЧТО, только О ЧЁМ (о разводе) или С ЧЕМ (с просьбой о разводе). С предлогом НА употребляется только в сочетании "заявление НА чьё-то имя". См. Словарь сочетаемости слов русского языка под ред. П.Н.Денисова, В.В.Морковкина, а также ответ на вопрос № 287688 на сайте "Грамота.ру". Исключение, пожалуй, составляет только "заявление НА отпуск".

Comment: Заявление может быть "на что". См. словарь сочетаемости Розенталя (rus-yaz.niv.ru/doc/punctuation-rosental/fc/…). Ответ Грамоты касается конкретного случая, а не вообще использования "на".